# Premiere Pro CC won't import exported image from Lightroom

Tags: premiere, video-quality, raw

I have a timelapse I shot on my Camera and developed the raw-images in Lightroom. Now I've exported them to a folder called, each file called like file_1.jpg, file_2.jpg, etc.

Whenever I import one or more (as an image sequence) files into Premiere, I get a bad picture. It has a lot of viewable pixels and red stripes all over it. Only when I move forward in a sequence, I can see the original (how I want it to be), but after that the image is replaced with something that looks like this:

[image: Bad Image]

Here is the good image:

[image: Good image]

Comment: Similar issue in this question - http://video.stackexchange.com/q/16244/1871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are very good that you are presently running the initial version of El Capitan (OSX 10.11).  The work-around suggested by Adobe is to change Premiere's Mercury Rendering engine from GPU to CPU (software-only).  That really wrecks rendering performance, but it does solve the problem.

Chances are also very good that if you install the update (OSX 10.11.1) the red-and-yellow pixel stripes will go away, even with the Mercury Rendering engine set to GPU (OpenCL).